# Angular UI-router Deep routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[From the UI-router Doc](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views), it says that for each state, you can set up multiple view and provide a different template and controller for each. So for my example, say I have a state provided that looks like this

```
.state('eventmenu.home', {
     url: "/home",
     views: {
       'menuContent':{templateUrl:"home.html"},
       'menulist' :{templateUrl: "list.html" }
     }})
```

So for the views, how would I be able to split off from there and set up a separate nested state for each one. This way my `menulist` can have multiple views, and my `menuContent` can as well, but both independent of each other.

[I have a codepen](http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/xgfsa) set up with a basic boilerplate that has the content and menu views created, I'm just stuck on this next part. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this may not be an answer but I am new in this forum with low reputation that I cannot comment yet.

Think about if you really need states to do this. Maybe you are better off with using directives to split your menuContent and menuList. Using states to divide sections of a page is a bit confusing and cluttered. If you use directives, you can still have your own controllers embedded in the html via ng-controller="".

Comment: I figured I'd give this a shot with states because I could easily change views and set up sub-menus a bit easier. I'll dig around for directives though and give it a shot. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem. I was in the same situation before, and I got pretty side-tracked by the rich features of the ui router. But I guess that ui router is best used if you intend to create "states" and not "templates", in which a directive is more suited for. We found out that our code got cleaner and easier to understand by just using directives for templating.